# mysqli_fetch always return null

Tags: php

Im simply trying to display results from a query Im running. When I run the query I am told that I have 6 fields.

But when I fetch it, it return null.

```
<?php           
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/administrator/components/com_memberportal/Default/Default.php');                  //Include functions & other needed default-settings

    $selected_event = 1;
    $searchq = "jo";

    $search_query = "SELECT b6vjp_user_info.id, b6vjp_user_info.academic_title, b6vjp_user_info.firstname, b6vjp_user_info.lastname, b6vjp_invitation.participated, b6vjp_organisation.name 
                     FROM b6vjp_user_info
                     INNER JOIN b6vjp_invitation ON b6vjp_user_info.id=b6vjp_invitation.user_info_id
                     INNER JOIN b6vjp_organisation_assignment ON b6vjp_user_info.id=b6vjp_organisation_assignment.user_info_id
                     INNER JOIN b6vjp_organisation ON b6vjp_organisation_assignment.organisation_id=b6vjp_organisation.id
                     INNER JOIN b6vjp_membership ON b6vjp_user_info.id=b6vjp_membership.user_info_id
                     WHERE b6vjp_user_info.id = b6vjp_invitation.user_info_id AND b6vjp_membership.group_id='1' AND b6vjp_invitation.event_id = '$Event_id' AND b6vjp_user_info.firstname LIKE '%$searchq%'
                     OR b6vjp_user_info.id = b6vjp_invitation.user_info_id AND b6vjp_membership.group_id='1' AND b6vjp_invitation.event_id = '$Event_id' AND b6vjp_user_info.lastname LIKE '%$searchq%'";

    $search_data = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'], $search_query);
    $search_data_fetched = mysqli_fetch_array($search_data);



    print_r($search_data);
?>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
<?php 

    echo "Im not empty! Look:" . print_r($search_data_fetched);
```

Heres the output:

[image]

Ive tried fetch_all, fetch all($search_data_fetched, MYSQLI_ASSOC), fetch_array, fetch_assoc.

I have double checked the Query, its correct.

Edit: My big mouth. It actually was the query. I was using the wrong variable. Sorry!

Why would it "convert" my results to null when fetching?

Comment: There are 6 fields, but 0 rows in the result

Comment: @KarstenKoop So the Query does fail. But when I run the query in my DB it comes back like expected. Any Idea why it would fail like this? Edit: Nevermind, found it. Updating Post now.